# Authenticating with "remember me" not persisting beyond a few hours

Tags: authentication

I'm using Sitecore 9.1.1 and logging users into the front-end of my site using the `AuthenticationManager.Login(domainUser, password, persist)` call. By default I'm sending "true" for the persist variable. My understanding is this should keep them logged in indefinitely, but it seems after a few hours their authentication expires and they have to log in again. The client wants to keep the user logged in for at least 24 hours.

Is this a case where I should be adding on a manual "FormsAuthenticationTicket" call to increase the timeout of the authentication cookie, or is there a method/setting to use to change that expiration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your solution is using OWIN authentication with Identity Server (enabled by default in SC 9.1+ instances), you should be able to change the default 30 minutes lifetime of the OWIN authentication cookie (`.Aspnet.Cookies`) making the following changes:

1. Patch the `ExpireTimeSpan` parameter of the `CookieAuthentication` processor in your Sitecore web application:

```
<pipelines>
      <owin.initialize>
        <processor name="CookieAuthentication" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.Initialize.CookieAuthentication, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
          <ExpireTimeSpan>0:00:30:00</ExpireTimeSpan>
        </processor>
      </owin.initialize>
</pipelines>
```

2. Modify the `CookieLifetime` parameter in the `\sitecore\Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer\Config\identityServer.xml` configuration file in your Identity Server host application:

```
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <IdentityServer>
      <Authentication>
        <CookieLifetime>0.00:30:00</CookieLifetime>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your configuration values for the `timeout` setting in the `system.web` section of the `web.config` file. Note the values are in minutes, for example below snippet shows both session state timeout and authentication timeout set to 30 minutes.

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None">
      <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="30"/>
    </authentication>
    <sessionState timeout="30" regenerateExpiredSessionId="false"/>
  </system.web>
```